# Is the contact permission key required to prevent crash with EKEventEditViewController?

Tags: ios, permissions, privacy

I've encountered an edge case bug where, when using an EKEventEditViewController and then going into the Locations View, the app will crash if there is no key for contact permission in the Info.plist. This is because the Location view inside EKEventEditViewController uses contacts to search for addresses. This happens when doing a typical: `root.present(editController, animated:true, completion:nil)` of the EKEventEditViewController with calendar permission granted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the similar crash in a background thread - *Crashed: com.apple.root.default-qos*.
I came up with the same conclussion - app tries to get access to contacts. But documentation says nothing about it.
I have added the *NSContactsUsageDescription* string into a plist and problem is gone.